# Unable to commit empty .gitkeep file

Tags: git

I have an existing git repo and want to commit some empty folders to establish a directory structure for future work. The general consensus for accomplishing this is to add an empty file named .gitkeep (or just .keep) to whatever directory you want to be able to commit.

However, I am unable to add that file to the repo if it's totally empty. If I add a single space to the file it works, but everywhere I've looked it said explicitly that the file would be empty (create it using touch and add in a single command).

I have git version 2.18.0 - is this a new restriction in newer versions of git, or is there a setting somewhere controlling this?

Comment: Git should store an empty file with no problem. I use an empty `.gitignore` rather than `.gitkeep` or `.keep` for this though, in part because I usually have some files I'll end up `.gitignore`-ing in the directory eventually, and in part because everything else already understands that `.gitignore` is a file meant for Git, not for it.

Comment: What error messages or failure case are you seeing?  Also, what operating system are you using?  This shouldn't be a problem in core Git, but we might be able to provide a better answer pointing to the right cause if we had more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working just fine in a brand new repo:

```
vonc@VONCM D:\git\tests
> git init aaa
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/git/tests/aaa/.git/

vonc@VONCM D:\git\tests
> cd aaa

vonc@VONCM D:\git\tests\aaa
> touch .gitignore

vonc@VONCM D:\git\tests\aaa
> git add .

vonc@VONCM D:\git\tests\aaa
> git commit -m "test adding empty file"
[master (root-commit) f103a40] test adding empty file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore

vonc@VONCM D:\git\tests\aaa
> gl
* f103a40  - (HEAD -> master) test adding empty file (9 seconds ago) VonC
```